# What is a boundary condition?

Tags: definition, boundary-conditions

While I've been doing my university homework, I've come across a question asking for the boundary condition for the electric flux density of a charged conductor. However, I seem to be stuck as I realise I don't really know the meaning of a 'boundary condition'. I've always taken it to be the limits in a definite integral, but somehow I don't feel that is the case. Searching up online gives me explanations with big words which I can't catch onto, such as the it being "a condition that is required to be satisfied at all or part of the boundary of a region in which a set of differential conditions is to be solved."

Can anyone offer a more dumbed down explanation of what [boundary conditions](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=boundary+conditions) are?

Comment: @DavidWhite: Why not turn that into an answer?

Comment: @KyleKanos, I considered my comment to be a bit too simplistic to serve as an official answer, but I took your advice and posted it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

In physics, you will deal with *differential equations* which relate functions and their derivatives; a solution to such an equation is an unknown function, *a priori*.

A *boundary condition* is a type of condition or requirement we place on this function. I'll present an example; the mathematical details are not so important here, as long as you grasp the idea of a boundary condition.

---

**Illustrative Example: Injecting into a tube**

Suppose we have a tube of some length $L$ and it is sealed at both ends. Now imagine we take a needle and inject a substance; how this diffuses is described by the diffusion equation for $c(x,t)$, the concentration of the substance:

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2}$$

where $D$ is a constant. *The equation itself is not important!* Now, so far we can write down a general solution describing how it will disperse, but we need to specialise to our specific case to get a physically applicable answer.

Remember the tubes were sealed at both ends; this means the flow of the substance at either end of the tube has to be zero. It turns out this is proportional to the first derivative, $\partial_x c$ of the concentration. So, we'd like this to be zero at both ends:

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} \bigg\rvert_{x = 0} = 0, \quad \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} \bigg\rvert_{x = L} = 0.$$

(To complete the problem, we'd also describe what the concentration is like initially; in this case it is of the form, $c(x,0) \sim \delta(x)$ since we inject it all at a point.)

The big picture is: *boundary conditions apply constraints on solutions to equations that are motivated by the physical problem being considered*. In this example, we are imposing the fact that the tube which is really the domain of the function, is sealed at both ends.

Answer (score 3):

A boundary condition is a known value that must be true for the problem that you are working. Example: if I am sitting at a stop light and the light turns green, I absolutely know that my vehicle starts from rest as I accelerate through the (now) green light. This is a boundary condition for a physics problem involving distance, velocity, and acceleration vs. time for the automobile that I am driving. Also note - boundary conditions are usually used to evaluate constants of integration when you are performing an indefinite integral.

Comment: This answer does not really distinguish a boundary condition from an "initial condition".

Answer (score 0):

As David White already stated: A boundary condition is an equation that gives you constraints of your problem you want to solve.

- So your vehicle being at rest at time $t=0$ is a boundary condition: $ v(t=0)=0$
- Or a grounded conducting sphere has the boundary condition of vanishing potential (grounded potential) in its volume and on the surface $\Phi(r<R)=0$
- Or and oscillating, on both ended fixed string has also two boundary conditions: It can't move on each end: e.g. $v(x=0)=0$, $v(x=L)=0$.

Also see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53455/dirichlet-and-neumann-boundary-condition-physical-example) for more quantitative description

Comment: You could add why they are needed for solving a problem.

Comment: Your vehicle example sounds more like initial conditions since you specify position (traffic light) and velocity, both at t=0.

Comment: Mathematically speaking there's no difference between initial and boundary conditions. Your domain simply includes a temporal dimension, and is bounded by a temporal boundary.